# Setting default location for a meeting in Microsoft Outlook (via VBA code)

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to implement a VBA project in Microsoft Outlook, which sets the default location for a meeting if one isn't specified.

As a user, when I try creating a meeting / calendar entry and do not specify a location, Outlook prompts me with the following message:

```
Outlook has detected the following:
- The location is not specified.
Do you want to send the meeting anyway?
Yes/No
```

There are many cases where a meeting’s location is understood, or written in the subject, or I’m simply scheduling some work for myself, so getting prompted all the time is very annoying.

I found some code here:
    http://blogs.technet.com/b/ewan/archive/2013/11/08/tip-o-the-week-196-change-outlook-meeting-duration.aspx

which changes the default Outlook appointment duration setting. I modified it to suit my requirements.

How I intended it to be was:

1. New appointments being created will have the text "(default)"
   pre-specified in the Location field.
2. Existing appointments being
   modified will not be altered.

Now the code below works fine for new appointments being created, but if I open an existing appointment and the value of the Location field is empty, it sets it to "(default)" which when closing the appointment prompts me to Save/Cancel (because it thinks I modified the item). That is not how I intended it to work.

Code at present:

```
Private objMeeting As clsMeeting

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set objMeeting = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
     Set objMeeting = New clsMeeting
End Sub

Private WithEvents olkIns As Outlook.Inspectors, _
        WithEvents olkApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set olkIns = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set olkIns = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olkApt_Unload()
    Set olkApt = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olkIns_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
        Set olkApt = Inspector.CurrentItem

            If Len(olkApt.Location) > 0 Then

            Else
                olkApt.Location = "(default)"
            End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @vba4all - thanks, thought I selected 'vb' as a tag, but in any case, vba is more appropriate

Comment: Other applications allow If Me.Dirty Then. http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Forms/Ifthedataintheformdirty.htm You could leave at least one character in location when creating, so Len(olkApt.Location) > 0 on existing calendar entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub olkIns_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.currentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
        Set olkApt = Inspector.currentItem

        If olkApt.Saved = False Then

            If Len(olkApt.location) > 0 Then

            Else
                olkApt.location = "(default)"
            End If
        End If

    End If

    Set olkApt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `olkApt.Saved = False` will not work in this instance, as new appointments always has this value as `True`.  Instead, try:

```
Private Sub olkIns_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
        Set olkApt = Inspector.CurrentItem
        If olkApt.CreationTime = #1/1/4501# Then
            olkApt.Location = DEFAULT_LOCATION
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

> > Update:  I've implemented this code and it works great...except when I have created a calendar invite with attendees.  After the event is saved, I perform a drag and drop to change the event date / time.  I am prompted to Save and send notifications, which I do; however, the visual placement of the event "jumps" back to the original spot, even though the content of the event still shows the newly modified date / time.

So, I have a calendar event where the visual representation on the calendar screen does not match the details of the event.

Any ideas on this?